# get name from id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables :

1. tbl_member (User Table)
2. tbl_recipe (Recipe Table)
3. tbl_fav (User Wishlist or Favourite Recipe Table)

```
Table 1: tbl_member:
mem_id
mem_uname
mem_email
mem_pass

Table 2: tbl_recipe
rec_id
rec_name
rec_preptime
rec_cooktime
rec_desc

Table 3: tbl_fav:
fav_id(pk)
rec_id(fk)
mem_id(fk)
```

**i need a query which can fetch all the details of recipe from `rec_id` when i provide `mem_id`?**
Please Help

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_recipe r JOIN tbl_fav f ON f.rec_id = r.rec_id JOIN tbl_member m ON m.mem_id = f.mem_id WHERE f.mem_id = :memId`

Comment: @Justinas I don't think you need the `JOIN` to `tbl_member`, because we already know the `mem_id` and it's recorded in `tbl_fav`

Comment: @Mehul FYI: I personally wouldn't add the prefix `tbl_` to a MySQL table. Since those are tables it should be clear that they are tables and they won't need a prefix to show that those are tables

Comment: @yunzen Pivot tables may contain reference to non-existing entity if setup without FK's, that's why I suggest joining all 3

Comment: @Justinas The structure of Table 3 as stated in OP suggests that the fields `rec_id` and `mem_id` are setup as foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with

```
   SELECT R.* 
     FROM tbl_recipe R
     JOIN tbl_fav F 
       ON R.rec_id = F.rec_id
    WHERE F.mem_id = {X}
```

wehere {X} is the `mem_id` you are searching for

Comment: thank you so much its been a great help everyone and yunzen specially

Comment: @MehulPanchal Keep going to learn. You will be rewarded.